# How to remove built-in 3G/4G modem from Thinkpad T440s?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, thinkpad

I bought a Thinkpad T440s, it has a 3G/4G modem card. This card blocks a slot that I need for my M2 SDD card:
[image]

I do not have any mobile card in my Laptop, so I conclude that I will probably not need a 3G/4G modem card. It was connected with two cables, one on the **Main** socket and one on the **AUX** socket. I switched the AUX cable to the Wireless-N care. The **Main** cable is just hanging around. Is that how to remove the AirPrime card? Is it okay to have the yellow main cable hanging around?

Comment: It appears you have already removed the card.  What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Ramhound I removed the card, and pluged out the AUX and MAIN cable. I thought I was done. Then I realized, that the WLAN signal was extremly week. I fixed it, by plugging in the AUX cable that was connected to the AirPrime card with my Wireless card. It looks like everything is working, but I am seeking for a) confirmation that this is correct and b) confirmation that I do not need to plugin the main cable anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the T440S Hardware Maintenance Manual.

[T440S HMM](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t440s_hmm_en_sp40a25360_04.pdf)

The steps below give you the color codes for the wires

I think from your description that you should be OK

=========

1040 Wireless LAN card (correction to this post)

When installing:

Plug the gray cable into the connector labeled MAIN or 1 on the card

Plug the black cable into the connector labeled AUX or 2 on the card

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing me to the docs. It actually states that one should connect the grey cable with the the card (not the blue one), so I changed it, so I am not using blue nor grey currently

Comment: I looked later in a T410  I have here and the wire is grey.  I  am glad this is all working for you.